# Solution to allow Python script to open any file in a directory, instead of hardcoded name

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a Python script which opens a file and processes the contents ultimately creating a separate output file that I need to provide to other individuals.  The problem is that this script will need to be run every day, and the file I open with the script will not have the same filename every day.  So I know I can't hardcode the filename into the csv.reader(open(...) portion of the script.

While I could always just rename the file I receive to match the filename hardcoded into the script, this is not ideal as I would have to do this every day and I would be manipulating the original file, which is not ok.  I am hoping there is an easy solution to modify my script to either open any file that ends with a particular extension (i.e. - .csv), or maybe there is a GUI solution via tkinter or wxpython that I could use to create a simple browse for file interface that will pass the name of the file selected into the portion of the script that opens the file.

Here's a sample of my script that I need to fix:

```
import csv

bs_ref = csv.reader(open('inputfile_14022011.csv','rb'))

<rest of script then processes the contents of the imported file but is not relevant to the question>
```

I would like to replace 'inputfile_14022001.csv' with something that allows any filename to potentially be called for that specific part of the script. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything useful for creating a file browser interface that can be used to pass the selected filename to a specific portion of my script.

Thank you for any help someone can provide.

Comment: Are you looking for an interactive solution (with a GUI), or are you looking for something that can run unattended (such as "pick the latest `inputfile_*.csv` file")?

Comment: Good question. Probably interactive so that I know the proper file is being processed. There is a ton of data being processed so checking it after the script finishes wouldn't be an easy task.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged wxpython, it can be something like this (untested) fragment:

```
from wxPython.wx import *
...
application = wxPySimpleApp()
...
dialog = wxFileDialog ( None, style = wxOPEN )
if dialog.ShowModal() == wxID_OK:
   print 'Selected:', dialog.GetPath()
   bs_ref = csv.reader(open(dialog.GetPath(),'rb'))
```

Comment: I tried this out and it looks like it's working perfectly!  Thank you very much. I appreciate your quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob

possible_filenames = glob.glob("*.csv")

# If you expect there to be only ONE file...
the_filename = possible_filenames[0]
```